# Nginx config to allow custom domains in app

Tags: laravel, nginx, multi-tenant, forge

I have a multi-tenancy app hosted on DO. Users are able to create subdomains and also set their preferred custom domain. Need help in setting up the right Nginx config, here is the current one:

Requirements:

1- User setup for their required subdomain on app's domain (with SSL) - WORKING

2- User setup for their own custom domain - for this I have set up an A record to the server IP and below is the Nginx config - NOT WORKING

3- User custom domain is loaded with SSL - need help on how to structure this? Would an A record suffice?

```
#FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/wiki.pk/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name .one.com "";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .one.com "";
    #server_name ~.;
    #server_name _;
    #server_name ~^(?.*)$;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/one.com/public;

    #FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/one.com/1233982/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/one.com/1233982/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    #FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/one.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/one.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

#FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/one.com/after/*;
```

Would appreciate all the help.